# Spring REST Security implementation?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, oauth, spring-security

I want to secure my rest services with spring security using token based authentication.

My approach here is with the help of filters every request has to validate whether it have a valid access token which is already created through loginservice and saved in hashmap.

Now what am excepting here is all the process done so far is handled by developer . How it can be given to spring security to handle all those stuffs?

Is  OAuth is suits for this rest service authentication?

Thanks in advance